# Jquery how to i append array loop

Tags: jquery

from this code how to show like  this

```
div 1 = left 
div 2 = right  
div 3 = left 
div 4 = right  
...etc........
```

> ้how to append (left , right , left , right) in div

```
<style>.left{float:left}.right{float:right}</style>
 <script>
 $('.nextg').live('click',function(){
var messages = ["left", "right"],
messageY= messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
$(document.body).append('<li class="'+messageY+'">'+messageY+'</li><br />');
});
</script>
<span class="nextg">Click view</span><div id="tupdate"></div>
```

Comment: As it is, this makes no sense.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think I've got what you're after. Take a look at my answer and let me know.

Comment: your code 's good but i want show like this ..when click 1 random left and click 2 i want to show right ..click 3 show left ..click 4 show right ...

Answer (score 0):

Like this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GwS6H/1/):

```
$('.nextg').live('click', function () {
    var messages = ['left', 'right'];
    var messageResult = function () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length) + 0;
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       var messageY = messageResult()
       $('body').append('<li class="'+messages[messageY]+'">'+messages[messageY]+'</li><br />');
    };

});
```